# Ubuntu doesn't set LC_ALL, why?

Tags: locale

If you run `locale` on an Ubuntu installation you get something like:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

How come LC_ALL is unset? I know how to set it, but why doesn't Ubuntu set it automatically, like with the other LC_'s?

Comment: I do not think it is recommended to do this because it will override all your other locale settings.

Comment: If you would like to know how to change that let me know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If LC_ALL is set it overrides the values of all the other LC_ variables. Hence setting it by default would have the same effect for your locale settings as setting all the LC variables but would make it more difficult to change only some of the values.